# VS2012 Database project import only specific schema

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-schema, database-project

I have created a Database Project in VS 2012.

Currently when I use the import option I do not see any means to filter out the schemas that I don't want. I can either import the whole DB or nothing at all.

However, I need to import only those database objects that belong to a particular schema (e.g. import only the objects in Schema 'User')

Is this even possible? If yes, how?

Thanks,
Rashmi

Comment: Perhaps start by not importing anything, then doing a compare of the DB to the Project to limit what you pull in? You'd still have to filter objects by selecting them, but it should give you some freedom to limit what you import.  Alternatively - pull in everything, delete the folders/schemas you don't want. It might be easier/quicker to handle that if there are quite a few objects.